# What's the difference between VM and VPS?

Tags: virtual-machine, vps

We often hear about VPS(Virtual Private Servers) and VM(Virtual Machine), is there any difference between them, or mean the same?

Comment: I would say that VPS implies that the VM comes preconfigured in some way. So a VPS is arguably a VM intended to be used as a server and setup for that purpose ahead of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is probably about full system level virtualization:

The term "Virtual Machine" is generally used to describe a *technology*, while the term "Virtual Private Server" (or "virtual root server", "virtual dedicated server" in some regions) is generally used to describe a *product*.

"VPS" usually means a server that you rent from a hosting company, together with remote management and such. Here 'virtual' doesn't refer to a specific technology, it merely means that it isn't dedicated hardware. Most VPSes are VMs (often Xen or Linux-KVM), but not always – cheap ones could be container-based (often OpenVZ or FreeBSD Jails).

---

Note that there are also other kinds of "virtual machines" that do not emulate a whole computer system at all – for example, the Java or .NET runtimes are often called "virtual machines" just because they execute code like a CPU would.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between [vm vs vps](https://www.bluepreneurs.com/vm-vs-vps-difference/) is that VM is a general term for any software-based emulation of a computer system, while VPS is a specific type of hosting service that uses VM technology to provide customers with more flexibility and control over their server environment

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Answer (score -2):

VM is `Virtual Machine` it means that you have your own workstation were you have to install many software or setup your own server.

it is type of machine like your computer but work like virtual.on Vm you can set lots of server may be public/private/hybride

your OS (operating System) windows,linux..etc
         ->
your VM (Virtual Machine) like Vmware
         ->
installed software/server.

and `VPS (Virtual Private Server)` is an type of your private server were whatever thing has been setup or installed these are done by you.it has acess by you only not for all. which has been install on your VM(virtual machine) or on your hardware which is known as bare-metal.

Comment: This is wrong. A VPS can come preinstalled/configured by others. VMs can be, but are not necessarily workstations.

Comment: it is write @davidgo and you also are correct but no need to put downvote.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Unfortunately downvoting incorrect answers is important to the site so that best answers bubble to the top. Especially in the case of this vote its not very importantfrom a reputation POV  as it did not reduce your reputation (which can't go below 1, and only costs you 1 - and unlike upvotes, down votes cost the giver as well).